# Custom order on string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

I have a `project` model. Projects have a `code` attribute, which is in `AAXXXX-YY` format like `"AA0001-18"`, `"ZA0012-19"`, where `AA` is two characters, `XXXX` is a progressive number, and `YY` is the last two digits of the year of its creation.

I need to define a default scope that orders projects by `code` in a way that the year takes precedence over the other part. Supposing I have the codes `"ZZ0001-17"`, `"AA0001-18"`, and `"ZZ002-17"`, `"ZZ001-17"` is first, `"ZZ002-17"` is second, and `"AA001-18"` is third.

I tried:

```
default_scope { order(:code) }
```

but I get `"AA001-18"` first.

Comment: What database software are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

`order("substring(code from '..$') ASC, code ASC")`

### Wait but why?

So as you said, you want to basically sort by 2 things:

1. the last 2 characters in the code string. `YY`
2. the rest of the code `AAXXXX-`

So first things first,

the order function as per Rails [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) will take the arguments you added and use them in the ORDER BY clause of the query.

Then, the substring function according to the [documentation of PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) is:

`substring(string from pattern)`

If we want **2 characters** `..` from the **end of the string** `$` we use `..$`

Hence, `substring(code from '..$')`

For more information about pattern matching please refer to the [documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html).

Now finally, with the second part of our ordering the `code` which already will act as a sorter for all the preceding characters `AAXXXX-`.

Comment: It seems to work. Can you please explain to me the substring thing? Thanks

Comment: Please check it and tell me if you need any more explanation. :)